# Deal with a question that doesn't have a proper answer But might help others

Tags: discussion, comments

I have asked [this question about Logstash service not being recognized in an Amazon Linux server](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/495305/logstash-unrecognized-service-amazon-linux) in Unix & Linux recently. Please read it carefully before evaluating this question. At the time that I asked the question, I needed a quick fix. After asking the question,I got some helpful answers (as comments to my original question, but technically not as answers).

However, none of them provided the fix I initially needed. Eventually, I had to relaunch a new server with Amazon Linux 2 (as the user 'Yaron' has suggested in his comment). It apparently solved my issue and I was able to run Logstash but IMO it's a work-around, as I couldn't run Logstash in the my initial server as I first intended to and I haven't come across any article saying that Logstash cannot be run in Amazon Linux 1.

So I am scratching my head about what should I do with this question.
There's no answer to be accepted as the suggestions were given as comments to the original answer. While it didn't provide me a direct solution, it helped me with doing a workaround. I don't want to delete the question either, as I believe the question and the comments might benefit any other person who would be having a similar kind of issue.

I found [this question How to deal with questions answered in comments](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4150/how-should-we-deal-with-question-answered-in-the-comments), but it really does not give the solution I'm seeking for, as in this case comments haven't provided a concrete fix to the original question.

Comment: If the only fix you found was reinstalling, you can just post an answer saying that and accept it. Or I can close the question as non-reproducible (since a reinstall fixed it, it was probably something very specific to your setup and unlikely to help future users).

Comment: @terdon thank you. After closing the question,will the users be able to view that and its comments in the future? Because I feel it's like 'intellectual theft' to post the gist of the comments as the answer and then accepting it myself and I'd rather see the question closed and let it be visible for anyone.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If the only fix you found was reinstalling, you can just post an answer saying that and accept it. Or I can close the question as non-reproducible (since a reinstall fixed it, it was probably something very specific to your setup and unlikely to help future users).

And don't worry about "intellectual theft". Answers belong in the answers and have no business being in the comments. In any case, from what you describe, you took guidance from the comments, not a full answer. So just post your solution and the question can be marked as answered.